# Embedding planar graphs into the grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, discrete-geometry, topological-graph-theory

I've seen the following lemma in a paper. The result is by Valiant.

A planar graph $G$ with maximum degree $4$ can be embedded in the plane using $O(|V|)$ area in such a way that its vertices are at integer coordinates and its edges are drawn so that they are made up of line segments of the form $x=i$ or $y=j$, for integers $i$ and $j$.

I have two questions.

1. Although not explicitly stated i assume the embedding is planar too?
2. Is there anything regarding the shape of the area that the graph is embedded into other than the fact it's area is $O(|V|)$ ? More specifically can we for example ensure that the graph can be embedded in a $|V|\times |V|$ grid?

Comment: By some sort of continuity argument, one can always take the points of a planar embedding to be in $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$, and then scale everything up so that the coordinates will all be integers.  So the $O(|V|)$ bound would really seem to be the essential aspect of the result.

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: @j.c. It is likely *Universality Considerations in VLSI Circuits* http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tc/1981/02/06312176.pdf

Comment: Hi guys, just make sure i haven't misstated Valiant's result here is the paper where i found it stated http://ac.els-cdn.com/0012365X9090358O/1-s2.0-0012365X9090358O-main.pdf?_tid=9642b098-62cb-11e5-b554-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1443106404_9c96e8464e33b585968d7197471403ae it's on page 4 of the document under lemma 2.1. And yes the paper i'm referring to is the one mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a mistake in the paper?

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand, I think you have misstated Valiant's result.

Regarding $1$, yes the embedding is assumed to be planar, with the edges constrained to follow the 'edges' of the grid.  This is called a *rectilinear embedding*.  Note that only graphs with maximum degree 4 have rectilinear embeddings, hence the degree restriction.  Secondly, the *area* of the embedding is defined to be the area of the smallest box bounding the embedding. Thus, the $O(V)$ area condition is quite strong (in particular, the length or width is $O(\sqrt V)$).  Finally, Valiant's result is actually for *trees* with maximum degree $4$.  He showed that the $O(V)$ area condition is false in general; there are planar graphs with maximum degree 4 that require bounding area $O(V^2)$.

**Edit.**
For the benefit of others who have not followed the chat, here is a summary. The lemma  under consideration is Lemma 2.1 of the paper [Unit Disk Graphs](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090358O) by Clark, Colbourn and Johnson.  The lemma is due to [Valiant](http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tc/1981/02/06312176.pdf), but a typo was  was introduced by Clark, Colbourn and Johnson.  The $O(|V|)$ should be replaced by $O(|V|^2)$.

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge literature on this topic. Search for "orthogonal graph drawing". The best possible area bound is $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am not sure what Valiant proved, but as far as I know, the best result on planar graph embedding in the grid is [Schnyder's algorithm.](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/gina/schnyder/). De Fraysseix, Pach, Pollack (1990) show that an $n$-vertex graph can be embedded in a $n-2 
\times 2n -4 $ grid.

Comment: It looks like this algorithm does not require edges to be orthogonal to the $x$ and $y$ axis (i.e edges are horizontal and vertical lines).

Comment: @CBrosen Note that in rectilinear embeddings the edges are *not* horizontal and vertical lines; they are a union of horizontal and vertical line *segments*.

Comment: @Tony Huynh when you say union you mean a collection of horizontal and vertical lines joined by bends?

Comment: Yes, and the bends can only happen at integer points (the vertices are also constrained to lie on integer points).

Comment: Regarding the $O(|V|)$ should it be $O(|V|^{2})$?

Comment: It looks like a typo. If one allows edges to cross, Valiant proved that $O(V (\log V)^2)$ area suffices, but he was not sure if $O(V)$ is possible in this case.